# Column to vector/vector to column, Originlab

Tags: c++, windows, calculated-columns, originlab

I have a little and probably trivial problem at hand right now while programming in Origin C but I didn't find anything usefull via google...
I want to convert a column from my worksheet into a vector for different calculation steps and also I have to convert some vectors so I can export them as ascii files.
Lets say I have a worksheet like this:

```
1299,9001   175156,7021
1300,2001   175431,5957
1300,5001   175704,2139
1300,8001   175970,9028
1301,1001   176228,0081
1301,4001   176471,8757
1301,7001   176699,8998
1302,0001   176917,9282
1302,3001   177135,8932
1302,6001   177363,7539
```

... and then want to convert the second column into a vector.
The solution will probably be easy as pie but since I'm completely new to Origin and Google didn't want to help me, I'm relying on this community.

Edit: @Thomas Origin didn't seem to like this kind of code (it's not C++ but they are pretty alike). I half-solved this problem today... meaning it's almost working as planned but I get a command error everytime I'm running the programm, telling me that a vectorelement-index is above the upper limit (Origin C error 24). It doesn't tell me where exactly the error occurs though but I think it's at this little function

```
for (int i=0; i<=2*n; ++i)
{
    if ((i==0) || (i==2*n))
        sum0=column[a+i*h];
    if (i%2==1)
        sum1=column[a+i*h];
    if ((i%2==0) && (i!=2*n))
        sum2=column[a+i*h];
    vsimpson[i]=(h/3)*(sum0+4*sum1+2*sum2);
}
```

2nd Edit: deleted the first part of my function since the editor wouldn't format it right.

Solution: I've rewritten the whole program in C#...

Comment: Are the columns separated by comma or space?  There could be two columns or four.

Comment: What is not working?  Which line generates the error?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Does the expression `a + i*h` evaluate to an index that is out of bounds for an array?

Answer (score 0):

Read the four values on each line.  Ignore the values you don't want and put the remaining value into a vector.

```
std::vector<unsigned int> vector_column_2;
std::vector< std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > vector_pair_column_2;
unsigned int column1, column2, column3, column 4; 
char comma1, comma2; 
//...
while (data_file >> column1 >> comma1 >> column2 >> column3 >> comma2 >> column4)
{
    vector_column_2.push_back(column_2);
    std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> col2_pair;
    col2_pair.first = column3;
    col2_pair.second = column4;
    vector_pair_column_2.push_back(col2_pair);
}
```

**Edit 1: Code fragment analysis**
Code:

```
for (int i=0; i<=2*n; ++i)
{
    if ((i==0) || (i==2*n))
        sum0=column[a+i*h];
    if (i%2==1)
        sum1=column[a+i*h];
    if ((i%2==0) && (i!=2*n))
        sum2=column[a+i*h];
    vsimpson[i]=(h/3)*(sum0+4*sum1+2*sum2);
}
```

The statement:
        if ((i==0) || (i==2*n))
            sum0=column[a+i*h];
can be partially factored out because the condition `(i == 0)` is an initialization, so the loop looks like:

```
sum0 = column[a]; // remember i==0, so i*h cancels out.
for (int i=0; i<=2*n; ++i)
{
    if (i==2*n)
        sum0=column[a+i*h];
    if (i%2==1)
        sum1=column[a+i*h];
    if ((i%2==0) && (i!=2*n))
        sum2=column[a+i*h];
    vsimpson[i]=(h/3)*(sum0+4*sum1+2*sum2);
}
```

The value `2*n` is a constant, so create one.
The index expression `a + i * h` is constant within the loop, so create a constant.

```
const unsigned int LIMIT = 2 * n; // or n << 1
sum0 = column[a]; // remember i==0, so i*h cancels out.
for (int i=0; i<=LIMIT; ++i)
{
    const unsigned int row = a + i * h;
    if (i==LIMIT)
        sum0=column[row];
    if (i%2==1)
        sum1=column[row];
    if ((i%2==0) && (i!=LIMIT))
        sum2=column[row];
    vsimpson[i]=(h/3)*(sum0+4*sum1+2*sum2);
}
```

The value at `column[row]` is accessed 3 times, so reduce it by using another variable.

```
const unsigned int LIMIT = 2 * n; // or n << 1
sum0 = column[a]; // remember i==0, so i*h cancels out.
for (int i=0; i<=LIMIT; ++i)
{
    const unsigned int row = a + i * h;
    const double value = column[row];
    if (i==LIMIT)
        sum0=value;
    if (i%2==1)
        sum1=value;
    if ((i%2==0) && (i!=LIMIT))
        sum2=value;
    vsimpson[i]=(h/3)*(sum0+4*sum1+2*sum2);
}
```

Do you really want "<=" as the terminating condition?
Many for loops are `i = 0 ; i < LIMIT; ++i`, note the use of `<` not `<=`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas,

those are only two values on each line, separated by space.
Since it is a German version of Origin it uses commas instead of dots as decimal mark.
I will try your code tomorrow and tell you if it worked.

Comment: Text was too long for comment section so I put it in the question as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try it on this way (you can tune the parameters):

```
    //select the current active worksheet
    //select the first column int the wks worksheet. Attention first column is the 0.
        int    column_to_vector()
        {
            Worksheet wks=Project.ActiveLayer();
            Column      col(wks, 0);
            vector      v(col, 2, 5, WRITEBACK_DELETE_ON_SHRINK | WRITEBACK_INSERT_ON_EXPAND); 
        }
        //select values between 2. and 5. row (including). Attention first row is the 0. Type -1,-1 for select all rows (probably you need this).
```

or:

```
void column_to_vector()
    {
        Worksheet wks=Project.ActiveLayer();
        if (wks)
        {
            Dataset dsB(wks,1);       
            dsB.SetSize(5);              // Set sizeof data set to 5          
            dsB[0]=-1;                   // You can change the values in rows and its size
            dsB[1]=5;
            dsB[2]=NANUM;                // Missing value will be removed
            dsB[3]=NANUM;                // Missing value will be removed
            dsB[4]=23;
            vector vB( dsB, TRUE );      // Copy Dataset dsD to vector vD removing missing values
            printf("The size of vB is %d", vB.GetSize()); // Elements dsB[2] and dsB[3] are removed 
        }
    }
```

For more about:

[Origin C: column constructor](https://www.originlab.com/doc/OriginC/ref/Column-Column),

[Origin C: dataset constructor](https://www.originlab.com/doc/OriginC/ref/Dataset-Dataset),

[Origin C: vector constructor](https://www.originlab.com/doc/OriginC/ref/vector-vector)